# Convert an 1D list into a 2D list of pairs

Tags: python, list

I have the list:

```py
[0, 15, 19, 26, 34, 62]
```

How would I go about converting it into the following?

```py
[[0, 15], [19, 26], [34, 62]]
```

Comment: If your list is `l`, you can simply `pairs = list(zip(l[::2], l[1::2]))` or, if you really need the items to be lists as well, `pairs = [list(_) for _ in zip(l[::2], l[1::2])]`.

Comment: normally users should show what they tried, even if it failed

Comment: ... and here is another very _Pythonic_ but not so clear option: `pairs = [*map(list, zip(l[::2], l[1::2]))]`.

Comment: @HMH1013, check my updated comments. I already suggested that as well.

Comment: @accdias OK, I think we comment at the same time, so I didn't see your update. I have deleted.

Comment: :-) It seems like that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

arr = [0, 15, 19, 26, 34, 62]
np.reshape(arr, (-1, 2))
```

output:

```
array([[ 0, 15],
       [19, 26],
       [34, 62]])
```

Comment: Seems like an overkill using `numpy` for such a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

```
list = [0, 15, 19, 26, 34, 62]

new_list = []
for i in range(0, len(list), 2):
    new_list.append([list[i], list[i+1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution, list members must be even.

```
>>> a = [0, 15, 19, 26, 34, 62]
>>> [[a[l*2], a[l*2 + 1]] for l in range(int(len(a)/2))]
[[0, 15], [19, 26], [34, 62]]
```